# How to change the timezone for a SmartOS Global Zone?

Tags: timezone, smartos

The SmartOS Global Zone defaults to the UTC timezone.  I'd like to schedule some cron jobs, and I'd like them to automatically follow daylight saving time changes, without requiring me to manually change the UTC offset every time the daylight saving change occurs.

How can I change the timezone for my SmartOS Global Zone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two methods to do this. The first is to write a custom SMF manifest and place it in `/opt/custom/smf` - any manifests in this directory are imported automatically at boot.

The other method is to use `pkgin` to install the `smtools` package. This provides a script called `sm-set-timezone`.

See this [blog entry](http://www.perkin.org.uk/posts/smartos-global-zone-tweaks.html) by Jonathan Perkin, who works for Joyent for reference.

Comment: Hmm, on the Global Zone, `sm-set-timezone` doesn't seem to persist between reboots.  I'll try the SMF route.  Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work in Global Zone
````[root@44-8a-5b-9c-a1-01 ~]# date
August 16, 2016 09:54:23 PM UTC
[root@44-8a-5b-9c-a1-01 ~]# sm-set-timezone "Europe/Berlin"
* Setting timezone for global..
* Changed to timezone to Europe/Berlin.  You will need to reboot.
[root@44-8a-5b-9c-a1-01 ~]# date
August 16, 2016 09:54:33 PM UTC
````

Comment: Unfortunately it seems `smtools` package is not offered anymore via `pkgin` in GZ.